# Is it somehow possible to create a collection of Foo<T> objects where T is restricted to a non-nullable type?

Tags: c#, collections, nullable, non-nullable

Inside of a class I have the following struct

```
private struct StateGroup<TState> where TState : struct, IAgentState
{
    // ...
    // ComponentDataArray requires TState to be a struct as well!
    public ComponentDataArray<TState> AgentStates;
    // ...
}
```

and multiple objects of that type

```
[Inject] private StateGroup<Foo> _fooGroup;
[Inject] private StateGroup<Bar> _barGroup;
[Inject] private StateGroup<Baz> _bazGroup;
// ...
```

with the `Inject` attribute just marking target for automated dependency injection.

Inside the class I need to call the very same chunk of code for each `StateGroup` object and I want to add all of into a collection and iterate over it. However I cannot define any collection of type `StateGroup<IAgentState>[]` since it requires a non-nullable type parameter **and I must not remove the struct from the where clause** since the `ComponentDataArray` of `StateGroup` requires a struct as well!

Besides writing a method I manually call a dozen times for each `StateGroup` object, is there any reasonable way to add those to a collection and call that particular method for each element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create another interface for `StateGroup<TState>` without the `struct` constraint:

```
private interface IStateGroup<TState> where TState : IAgentState { }
```

Then we make StateGroup to implement the new interface:

```
private struct StateGroup<TState>: IStateGroup<IAgentState> where TState: struct, IAgentState { }
```

And testing:

```
var states = new List<IStateGroup<IAgentState>>();
var fooGroup = new StateGroup<Foo>();
var booGroup = new StateGroup<Boo>();
var mooGroup = new StateGroup<Moo>();
states.Add(fooGroup);
states.Add(booGroup);
states.Add(mooGroup);
```